# Core Data NSPredicate not returning records between two dates

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a CoreData entity `Comment` who has a parent entity `Measurement`.

The `Measurement` entity has a `measurementDate` attribute.

My Core Data database has 200 `Comment` records in it, each with varying `measurementDate` values over the last 3 years.

I'm trying to get the records where `measurementDate` is between any two given dates.

Firstly, I tried this:

```
//now fetch a record between 12 and 11 months ago
NSDate *startDate = [AppGlobals dateByAddingMonths:[NSDate date] withMonths:-12];
NSDate *endDate = [AppGlobals dateByAddingMonths:startDate withMonths:1];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(measurementDate >= %@) AND (measurementDate <= %@)", startDate, endDate];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Comment" inManagedObjectContext:self.context]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But I got 0 results.

So then I tried replacing my predicate with something simpler:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"measurementDate >= %@", startDate];
```

This should return approximately a third of my results.  But actually it returns ALL 200 RECORDS.

I've logged out the dates of the objects and it looks like the dates are being completely ignored!

What am I doing wrong???

Is it something to do with the Parent Abstract entity `Measurement` and because I'm fetching from the `Comment` entity and not the `Measurement` entity?
Is it because I'm using "scalar properties for primitive data types"  in my code?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should probably mention that my "measurementDateInterval" is located on an Abstract Entity (Measurement) which my Comment entity uses as it's parent entity.  Is this what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `measurementDateInterval` of type `NSDate`? The name suggests it's an *interval*, not a *date*. Can you print out `startDate` and `endDate`? What do the `measurementDateInterval` values of your objects look like?

Comment: You 2 predicates are identical. I assume that's a copy & paste error?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Edits applied appropriately.  measurementDate is an NSDate in Core Data, but note that I'm using primitive types when I extract the classes.  The start date logs out as 2012-04-08 16:33:31, and when logging out all 200 returned records, only a third of them are actually valid.  NB. measurementDate is located on the abstract entity which my Comment entity is the child of.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say **primitive types**. How are you setting the interval values?

Comment: Sorry.  I mean... when extracting the subclasses I checked "Use scalar properties for primitive data types".  i.e. my code uses NSTimeInterval instead of NSDate, however I don't think this is a problem because the predicate only accepts NSDate format values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the problem is where you assign the date value to the managed object. If `measurementDate` is defined as scalar property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval measurementDate;
```

then you assign an `NSDate` to it with

```
NSDate *theDate;
obj.measurementDate = [theDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Comment: Thanks. But there's no problem setting the dates.  When I query the 200 returned objects, they all have their correct dates set.  (I use timeIntervalSince1970 to set the dates, which seems to work fine.  Using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate gives the wrong dates when I query the returned objects.)

Comment: @theDuncs: I think you have to use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead of `timeIntervalSince1970`, because that is what Core Data uses for the conversion. Can you try it?

Comment: YOU'RE A GENIUS!  Martin R for president!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `NSDate` or use `NSTimeInterval` (primitive, since it’s really a `double`).

If you mix those, you’ll easily confuse yourself. Basically, an `NSDate` object is a class that wraps an `NSTimeInterval` value, i.e. a `double` -- nothing more. And `NSDate` adds lots of methods for working on that value.

The compiler should have given you a slew of warnings, though.

Comment: If you choose the option "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when creating the managed object subclasses in Xcode, the property is defined as `NSTimeInterval`. However, a predicate for a fetch request works only with an `NSDate` parameter (which is strange, but I tested it). So you have to know how Core Data converts between `NSDate` and `NSTimeInterval`, and that is what I wrote above.

Comment: Since I chose to use scalar properties, I set all my dates using the timeIntervalSince1970 function.  There's no problem setting the actual date - when I log out the 200 returned Comment objects, they show the correct dates from the last 3 years.

Comment: Daniel - I was using timeIntervalSince1970 but I should have been using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.  I'm an idiot.  Thanks for all your help!