# Saving creation date of a core data object

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Currently I'm creating a custom `List` object using `Core Data`. An attribute of `List` is creationDate. However, when I set its `Attribute Type` to Date and then generate the object class files, it comes up as `NSTimeInterval`. Is this supposed to happen?

If so, could somebody please explain the best way to save the object's creation date?

Comment: This might help if you use "scalar properties" for NSDate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884250/core-data-nspredicate-not-returning-records-between-two-dates/15885204#15885204.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generated the class files, you probablay checked the "Use scalar properties for primitive types" checkbox (it appears when you are asked to choose a folder). Uncheck it and Date attributes should become NSDates.[image]

Comment: Also, I prefer scalar objects for everything other than NSDate.  I have just manually changed NSTimeInterval to NSDate a few times and it has worked just fine.

Comment: @Borrrden is this really OK though? I agree with you that using scalar objects is better except for NSDate. Are you sure I won't get any weird behavior if I manually change it to NSDate? Thanks for your input

Comment: @Auser I have not noticed any bad effects from it.  I have noticed bad effects from doing the reverse though (i.e. changing NSNumber to float or something)