# Core Data: using boolean in auto-generated entity class

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Core Data has auto-generated an subclass of my `NSManagedObject`. My *entity* contains an *boolean* named *isActive*. When the subclass is auto-generated the type of this property is `NSNumber`. Since this is a boolean, I have to write code like:

```
if ([myEntity.isActive boolValue])
```

which I think i very odd. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to *solve*, really, that's normal and works as expected.

If you just don't like it, check the box marked "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when generating subclasses. Boolean properties will then be generated as `BOOL`, so there won't be any reason to call `boolValue` on them.

You also mention date attributes that end up as `NSTimeInterval` when you do that. I agree, that's annoying. But: **you can mix and match scalar and object properties**. There's nothing magic about the generation step, the code you see is all there is to it. So, generate using scalar properties, which gives you this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval myDate;
```

Then just edit that line to look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * created;
```

But leave your `isActive` property as-is. Voila, scalar access to one property but object-style access to another.

Comment: I tried that previously. But then my `NSDate` was changed to `NSTimeInterval`, which seems strange?

Comment: @DennisMadsen: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15885204/1187415 how to deal with a Date attribute stored as a scalar value.

Comment: @DennisMadsen: See edits, you can have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" checkbox when you generate subclasses using "Create NSManagedObject Subclass" option.