# How to use a predicate on NSTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nspredicate, unrecognized-selector

I would like to get all records for the current month, so I stack two predicates for first date of the month and last day of the month.  Since I use CoreData the dates are stored actually as NSTimeInterval.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

//Get beginning of current month
NSDateComponents *beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
[beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents setDay:1];
NSDate *beginningOfCurrentMonthDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents];

//Set a single month to be added to the current month
NSDateComponents *oneMonth = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneMonth setMonth:1];

//determine the last day of this month
NSDate *beginningOfNextMonthDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneMonth toDate:beginningOfCurrentMonthDate options:0];

NSMutableArray *parr = [NSMutableArray array];
[parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate >= %d", [beginningOfCurrentMonthDate timeIntervalSince1970]]];
[parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate < %d", [beginningOfNextMonthDate timeIntervalSince1970]]];

//Give me everything from beginning of this month until end of this month
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:parr];

return [allRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Upon returning the filtered array, it crashes with this error message:

```
2013-10-25 19:09:39.702 [3556:a0b] -[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8911440
2013-10-25 19:09:39.704 [3556:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8911440'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aa85e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182b8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b45903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9890b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a984ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01a7e3e3 -[NSDate compare:] + 67
    6   Foundation                          0x014194fe -[NSComparisonPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 408
    7   Foundation                          0x014b03de -[NSPredicateOperator performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 306
    8   Foundation                          0x014b016c -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 347
    9   Foundation                          0x014299b6 -[NSCompoundPredicateOperator evaluatePredicates:withObject:substitutionVariables:] + 240
    10  Foundation                          0x01429845 -[NSCompoundPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 294
    11  Foundation                          0x014b0009 -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 48
    12  Foundation                          0x014aff89 _filterObjectsUsingPredicate + 418
    13  Foundation                          0x014afd42 -[NSArray(NSPredicateSupport) filteredArrayUsingPredicate:] + 328
```

I used this loop also to indicate that the recordDate truly exists within the array:

```
for (FTRecord *r in allRecords) {
    NSLog(@"%f", [r recordDate]);
}

2013-10-25 19:09:35.860 [3556:a0b] 1380582000.000000
2013-10-25 19:09:36.556 [3556:a0b] 1380754800.000000
```

Comment: The stack trace shows that an `NSDate` object is involved in the predicate. Try changing your `NSPredicate` to compare `recordDate` against an `NSDate` instead of the time interval.

Comment: I just double checked everything. But you see that both dates are converted into NSTimeInterval though. I even did what you suggested, by deleting `timeIntervalSince1970` and it still crashes with the same message. BTW, I have now added how the dates were created, maybe it helps to track down the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You chose the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" option when
creating the managed object subclass, so that the recordDate is represented as
`NSTimeInterval` in the `FTRecord` class.

But in a predicate like `"recordDate >= 123.45"`, the left-hand side is stored
as a `NSKeyPathExpression`, and that uses `valueForKeyPath:@"recordDate"` to access the property, which returns an `NSDate` object.
The right-hand side of that predicate is stored as `NSConstantValueExpression`
with a reference to an `NSNumber` object.
Therefore an `NSDate` is compared with an `NSNumber`, which leads exactly to the
exception that you got.

To fix the problem, you have to compare the property with an `NSDate`
(which is what @rmaddy initially suggested):

```
[parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate >= %@", beginningOfCurrentMonthDate]];
[parr addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recordDate < %@", beginningOfNextMonthDate]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:parr];
```

I tested this and it seems to produce the expected result.

Note however that Core Data uses `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` and 
`dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to convert between the scalar
values and `NSDate`, not `timeIntervalSince1970`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just double checked, that is true the predicates now won't crash. However the filtered array shows no entry either. Itsa bit messy now. I wonder if I should re-generate the model without using scalar properties for primitive data types.  What is your advice here?

Comment: @Kave: See my final remark. I *assume* that you created the objects using `timeIntervalSince1970`, but you have to use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/15885204/1187415). If you don't use scalar properties then you get rid of all these conversion problems. But apart from that, I do not have real advice whether scalar properties are better or not.

Comment: Martin you were right.Deleting the app and changing it to `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` fixed the issue. THanks for this great analysis.  Eventually I will have to compare timestamps (irrelevant of recordDate) with incoming data from a REST service.  There the timestamp will be saved as unix timestamp (1970).  That's the reason I chose `timeIntervalSince1970` in first place to circumvent incompatibilities.  But it seems I can't do that after all. I suppose that would be a new question though.

Comment: @Kave: I have no experience with REST, so yes, a new question would be better.

Answer (score 2):

For solution in Swift 3:

```
let date = NSDate()
let calender = NSCalendar.current
var beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date as Date)

beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents.day = 1

let beginningOfCurrentMonthDate = calender.date(from: beginningOfCurrentMonthComponents)
let beginningOfNextMonth = calender.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: beginningOfCurrentMonthDate!)

let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", beginningOfCurrentMonthDate! as NSDate)
let pred2 = NSPredicate(format: "date < %@", beginningOfNextMonth! as NSDate)

let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [pred1, pred2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Will add timeIntervalSince1970 with in a predicate itself. It woul

NSPredicate* predicate = PREDICATE(@"(lastUpdatedTime == nil OR lastUpdatedTime.timeIntervalSince1970 <= %f)",currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970);